# Computer sometimes doesn't boot after power failure, what should I replace?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a new computer that behaves strange after a power failure. When I switch off the computer it will not boot anymore. Completely unplugging the computer for about an hour cures the issue for the next boot.

The internal leds are working

I have no idea where to start looking. What, in your opinion could be the cause of this strange behaviour ? My best bet would be to replace the power supply  Would that be a good place to start ?

Comment: "new computer" - first thought that springs to mind is "warranty" - take it in and let the manufacturer fix it.

Comment: different supplyers for different parts, first I need to know what is wrong before I can claim warrenty

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have a misbehaving power supply.  If the fans do not start when you press the power button, that indicates that the power supply is not turning on at all.  Try replacing the power supply and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this failure too but found a faster fix is to press Reset when unplugged for a second to discharge the voltage. Then you do not have wait for one hour.

This leads me to think the problem is with pwr OK issue on the motherboard or the PSU has some other power sequence unusual behavior or with standby power.

Regardless if the BIOS does not beep, there is a glitch in the power up sequence caused by the AC power fault  affecting the BIOS POST and prventing successful POST to trigger start of Boot.

Check BIOS versions for issues.  Or unplug and press Reset momentarily.

Comment: @user32510, I have tried that but for some strange reason the only thing that works is to wait.

The motherboard has a double bios. Switching from the latest bios version to default does not change anything. When I press the power button nothing happens, fan does not even start spinning.

Arjen

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely start by looking at the power supply as the source of the problem. But I would also check the CMOS battery (it should be a little coin-shaped battery somewhere on the motherboard). Next time this happens, remove the battery, discharge the voltage in the entire system (unplug the power supply then press and hold the power button for ~10 seconds), install the CMOS battery again, and see if that works.